# expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token function

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I am getting an `Expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token`
error when trying to create a new void function.

Here is the snippet:

I am not sure how this error is supposed to be resolved. I also have expected intiailizer before the `)` token as well.

```
using namespace std;

void ascii_to_bin()
{
    string test;
    int ascii;
    int asciibinary;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline (cin,test);
    for (i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
    {
        ascii = int(test[i]);
        bitset<8> asciibinary (ascii);
        cout << asciibinary << endl;
    }
}

void calculate_binary(string binarystring; int stringlen)
{
    int num_characters;
    num_characters = (stringlen) / 8;
    int binary[8];
    int asciinum;
    char asciichar;
    int j = 0;
    i = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < num_characters; y++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {

            binary[i] = (int)binarystring[j]-48;
            j++;
        }
        int power[8];
        int counter = 7;
        for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
        {
            power[c] = counter;
            counter --;
        }

        for(int z = 0; z < 8; z++)
        {
            double a = binary[z];
            double b = power[z];

            asciinum += a*pow(2,b);
            cout << asciinum << endl;
        }
        asciichar = asciinum;``

        cout << asciichar << endl;
        asciinum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your error message contain a line number? Have you checked that line number?

Comment: the fact you have 2 ticks at the end of this line is probably not helping : 
        asciichar = asciinum;``

Comment: Please tell us the line number that is being flagged, and the statement that is at that line number.

Comment: hello it is flagging line 18.  The line is void calculate_binary(string binarystring; int stringlen)

Comment: the tick marks don't show up in the code. only when i pasted it

Comment: Please *edit the question* to state the exact error message (including line number that matches the line number in the code as pasted in the question, you probably also want to restate an exact copy of that line so we know for sure which one it is).  This information needs to be *in the question*, not just a comment. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `void calculate_binary(string binarystring; int stringlen)` should become `void calculate_binary(string binarystring, int stringlen)` - You separated with a semicolon instead of a comma.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of this line:

```
void calculate_binary(string binarystring; int stringlen)
```

The semicolon should be a comma:

```
void calculate_binary(string binarystring, int stringlen)
```

A semicolon is used to separate statements, while a comma is used to separate multiple parameters to a function.